# Why does catch block never execute on the device?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, task-parallel-library, xamarin

Consider this code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine ("Throwing");
        throw new Exception ();
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine ("Gotcha!");
    }
});
```

On iOS Simulator, it prints `Throwing` and `Gotcha!` as expected.
However, **when compiled for the device**, it only prints `Throwing` and never prints `Gotcha!`.

Why does this happen?
I'm using MonoTouch 6.0.8.
I can also reproduce it on 6.0.6.

I put up a [sample project here, you can try to run it on the device](http://rghost.net/42418971).
(never mind the name—I was investigating a different crash when I found this).

Comment: Try looking at this previous stackoverflow post-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363495/difference-between-catch-block-and-throw-new-exception-in-method

Comment: @DJ: Not sure how it is relevant. I'm throwing an exception, and `catch` doesn't catch it.

Comment: @DJ, this is obviously a trivial example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Here's a similar bug report from Xamarin that claims it's been fixed in relase 5.3.4: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5423  . Have you tried updating your Monotouch version?

Comment: @Diego: Mine is the newest. :-) But this looks very similar indeed.

Comment: Dear downvoter: you're just like that `catch` block, so silent and mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that it only happens with LLVM enabled.
Perhaps it's a bug so I'll report it to Xamarin.

Interestingly, adding

```
BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    new UIAlertView ("Gotta catch 'em all!", "", null, "OK", null).Show ();
});
```

after `Console.WriteLine` call helps—I see both alert and log entry.

There's my [sample project](http://rghost.net/42418971).

Comment: It sure sounds like a bug!

Comment: Strangely, I can't reproduce it in another project. Hum hum.

Comment: For what it's worth, I could not repro it either in my project.  Hope you can track down the particulars. :)

Comment: @Kirk: Do all `Console.WriteLine` messages appear in Device Console?

Comment: Yes, it appears on the device's console as well.  (with LLVM enabled)

Comment: @Kirk: Can you please try [my project](http://rghost.net/42418971) (never mind the name; the code is in the controller's ViewDidLoad)?

Comment: @poupou: I attached a sample project if you feel like giving it a spin. I can reproduce it both on iPad 2 and iPad Mini with iOS 6.0.1. But I suppose it might be MonoTouch 6.0.8-only.

Comment: @DanAbramov please fill such issues on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so the right developers can fix them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a silly question but have the conditions been met to require the catch command?

If so perhaps the application breaks before returning the "Gotcha" and iOS commands take over.

I believe iOS listens to see if and when your command/application breaks because default functions kick in to handle this. Similar to the dealloc commands.

Comment: But the curious thing is the app doesn't crash.