# ForEach Loop exiting when handler is created - C#

Tags: c#, loops, menustrip

In my program, I am listing every logical drive inside of a menustrip.
To accomplish this, I use the following code

```
private ToolStripMenuItem[] getAllDrives()
    {
        //find the number of drives
        int arrayLength = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Count();

        //create array that can hold all drives
        ToolStripMenuItem[] drives = new ToolStripMenuItem[arrayLength];

        //populate array
        int currentSlot = 0;
        foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            drives[currentSlot].Name = d.Name;
            drives[currentSlot].Tag = d.Name;
            drives[currentSlot].Text = d.Name + " " + d.VolumeLabel;
            drives[currentSlot].Click += new EventHandler((se,e1) => driveClick(d.Name));
            currentSlot++;
        }
        return drives;
    }
```

However, it appears that for whatever reason, the loop exits when the drives[currentSlot].Name is modified. Why is it doing this?

Comment: For future question please provide exception details in the pose - "loop exits" is very non-specific explanation of problem. As it stands now your question is already answered in "Array Elements" section of [What is NullReferenceException and how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) question.

Comment: I will be more specific in future posts. The odd thing with this scenario is that no exception was being thrown, making it hard for me to pinpoint the exact cause of the error.

Comment: "no exception was being thrown" is very unlikely - you may be eating all exceptions in caller or above. Consider reading on good practice of exception handling i.e. starting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204814/is-there-any-valid-reason-to-ever-ignore-a-caught-exception.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov possible if this code is called in a Form_Load event in a 64bit environment from the Visual Studio Debugging Session --- oh well --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot to initialize `drives[currentSlot]`. It is null and you get an exception (*System.NullReferenceException*)

```
 drives[currentSlot] = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Rookie mistake by me. Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't your program crash with an exception? Did you catch and swallow the exception somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the item at `drives[currentSlot]` before attempting to access its properties, as such you'll likely be getting a `NullReferenceException` thrown, terminating your loop. Try adding:

```
drives[currentSlot] = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

at the start of the loop.