# Hide error without workaround

Tags: c#, winforms

In my code:

```
private void cbbMaoDeObra_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int resultado = Convert.ToInt32(cbbMaoDeObra.SelectedValue);
        if (resultado == 0)
        {
            btnConfirmar.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewStateWorkLogger = ViewStateWorkLogger.AbleToConfirm;
        }
        MaoDeObra = resultado;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I have a try-catch to deal with some errors. My dynamic program, when started, will have a variable of type `string` in cbbMaoDeObra and when it starts, this string is just 'letters' and can't be parsed. SelectedValue. This is because just after some events I initialize it and read from de Database. Then, without workarounds like I did up, like using return or leave the field empty, how can I deal with these errors?

Is `try { statement } catch { empty }` recommended to be used?

Comment: `catch{empty}` is definitely not recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally for parsing string values, the safer option is [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx). This will not raise the exception, instead it will return a `bool` indicating success or failure.

```
if(int.TryParse("123", out resultado))
{
   //parsing successful 
}
else
{
  // invalid input
}
```

but since `SelectedValue` is of type object, you can use `Convert.ToIn32` and safeguard against exception *(with try-catch)*, or convert your SelectedValue to string and then use `int.TryParse`.

```
string str = cbbMaoDeObra.SelectedValue as string;
if (str != null && int.TryParse(str, out resultado))
{
}
```

> Is try { statement } catch { empty } recommended to be used?

There are very few places where empty catch would be useful. See: [Is there any valid reason to ever ignore a caught exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204814/is-there-any-valid-reason-to-ever-ignore-a-caught-exception).
Don't use `catch(Exception)`, catch specific exception first, log/handle it. See [Best Practices for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: SelectedValue can't be parsed, as it is an object. int.TryParse will never compile this. Convert.ToInt32 will do it, but it becomes a workaround.

Comment: @TonyCamargo, are you targeting Winform ?